# How to write Do/While validation?

Tags: java

I'm currently taking an intro to Java class and I'd really like to improve but I'm struggling to complete this assignment. The requirements for the assignment was to

1. Implement a loop that allows the user to continue to play the game by typing yes.
2. Keep track of the users: Wins, Losses and Games Played using incrementing variables
3. When the user no longer wishes to continue, print their results displaying the tracked variables: Wins, Losses and Games Played
4. Implement an input validation loop to ensure the user enters correct input (h, t, H, T)

I believe I've done all but the last one, I've tried numerous times to use do and while loops but the closest I've gotten was the wrong input looping while the correct input would bypass all other if/while/else statements. If at all possible I'd greatly appreciate someone taking a look at my code and explaining what I could do better, and how I could complete or approach the last requirement.

Thank you!

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input, inputUpper;
    char userGuess;
    char coinFlip;
    int randNum;
    int wins = 0;
    int losses = 0;
    int total = 0;
    String choice = "yes";

    do {
        System.out.print("I will flip a coin guess 'H' for heads or 'T' for 
        tails --> ");
        input = scan.nextLine();

        inputUpper = input.toUpperCase();

        userGuess = inputUpper.charAt(0);
        randNum = (int) (Math.random() * 2);

        if(randNum == 0)
        {
            coinFlip = 'H';
        }
        else
        {
            coinFlip = 'T';
        }

        System.out.println("\nYou picked " + userGuess + 
        " and the coin flip was " + coinFlip + " so ...");

        if(userGuess == coinFlip)
        {
            System.out.println("You win!");
            wins ++;
            total ++;
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Better luck next time ...");
            losses ++;
            total ++;
        }
        System.out.println("Do you want to continue(yes/no)?");
        choice=scan.nextLine();
    } while(choice.equalsIgnoreCase("yes"));
    System.out.println("Thank you for playing.");
    System.out.println("You guessed correctly this many times: " +wins);
    System.out.println("You guessed incorrectly this many times: " +losses);
    System.out.println("During this session you've played this many games: " +total);
    }
}
```

I expect the program to require T/t or H/h in order to continue, and if the user inputs an incorrect letter or number it'll ask them to input t or h.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP is aksking for someone to do his/her homework

Comment: I'm sorry if it came off that way. I've emailed my professor regarding it and while he did offer some useful insight I was still unable to fully complete it on my own.  It wasn't my intention to come off as asking for the solution, I'm just new to the site and they suggested that I write what I want the program to do; I suppose so it would be easier to reply to since you know what the person wants? Thanks to Steve's insight I actually realized that the issue I was having was mostly due to me not providing another do/while since I used one do and two whiles it got really messy.

Comment: It's not off topic.  There are numerous posts about this on StackOverflow-Meta, like this one: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions.  We try to help students to really learn, but there is no inherent reason to treat a student question any differently than if they were a working programmer.  I chose to answer this question because the guy had put in a lot of good effort, and seemed to be legitimately confused after trying to solve the last part of the assignment.  And I remember burning out in college before finishing assignments.

Comment: One recommendation I would make is to use correct indentation (including the universal Java standard of putting opening braces on the same line).

Comment: I see, sorry about the poor formatting I've been haphazardly adding and removing lines of codes and making edits so it is rather messy.. I've never heard of the universal Java standard but I'll try to keep it in mind. Thank you.

Comment: @SvetlinZarev I disagree that the OP is _"asking for someone to do his/her homework"_. They posted a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and obviously had made a genuine effort to solve their problem before posting here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's a simple way to validate the input:

```
do {
    System.out.print("I will flip a coin guess 'H' for heads or 'T' for tails --> ");
    input = scan.nextLine();
    inputUpper = input.toUpperCase();
} while (!inputUpper.equals("T") && !inputUpper.equals("F"));
```

You could do the same thing at the end for "yes"/"no".

I think you did a pretty good job with this.

Comment: @JavaNovice Since Steve's solution seems to have solved your issue, please consider accepting this answer. That would be helpful for the community.